# I can not get access to my own MySQL server via RoR?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, ruby-on-rails-4

Okay, so I'm new to ruby and today I spent all day installing it and necessary gems...then uninstalled it and installed everything using RubyInstaller.

Anyway, everything is fine with my installation I think...

I also installed MySQL, and when start WEBrick like this
    rails server
But when I load up
    localhost:3000

I get this message:
    Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Whats on your `database.yml`

Comment: Have you set up your db on the MYSQL server?

Comment: # MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
#
# Install the MYSQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: simple_cms_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost

Comment: # Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: simple_cms_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: simple_cms_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your root user doesnt have a password in your sql server, you should add a blank in your database.yml file:

```
development:
  ...
  username: root
  password: ""
```

If your root user in the sql server has a password (probably yes), you should specify it in your database.yml

```
development:
  ...
  username: root
  password: pa$$word
```

**EDIT:**

For creating the database run

```
bundle exec rake db:create
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: I just added my password like you said, and thanks that worked but now I have a different problem. Now I get this message:

Unknown database 'simple_cms_development'

Rails.root: C:/Users/Jose/Documents/Sites/simple_cms

Comment: bundle exec rake db:create, followed by a bundle exec rake db:migrate

Comment: Actually, it did. I didn't have to use bundle exec. I just closed the cmd and did it rake db:create

Why does that happen? It's kind of annoying having a problem and then closing it then openning it and finding out the only problem was that it needed to be opened or closed again.

Thanks though.

Comment: I dont know... but using bundle exec is recommed, because it loads the specific version of your gems, which are listed in the gemfile. if you run it without the bundle exec, it loads the systemwide most recent version of the gems

Comment: I would be happy if you mark my answer as correct if it helped you =) thanks

Comment: I don't know how to do that >.>; Ill do it if you tell me how though I'm new t this site